# How to recover and load XMP from exported JPEG in darktable?

Tags: jpeg, darktable, xmp

I've lost a XMP file for the edit, which I very much like...

Luckily, I've got the RAW for the photo and the exported JPEG for the edit. And, digiKam is showing a tab with XMP profile (for the JPEG of the edit) with contents, that look a bit like history stack of Darktable.

If it's possible, how can I recover and load this XMP profile from JPEG to darktable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the XMP information (structured) via command line with `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -xmp -b image.jpg >name_of_raw.xmp
```

(replace **name_of_raw** with actual RAW file name). In case of need move XMP file in to the location of RAW file.
And then start Darktable.

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found [an answer](https://www.mail-archive.com/darktable-user@lists.darktable.org/msg12247.html) to load history stack straight from JPEG file:

1. open **lighttable**,
2. select RAW file,
3. expand module **history stack** in the right sidebar,
4. click **load sidecar file...**,
5. change filter to **show all files** instead of XMP sidecar files,
6. **select JPEG file** containing XMP profile.